# Slurm heterogeneous job for multiple tests

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

I have to perform some tests on an HPC cluster and I am using Slurm as workload manager.
Since I have to perform similar tests on different allocations, I decided to exploit the heterogenous job support for Slurm.
Here is my Slurm script:

```
# begin of slurm_script.sh
#!/bin/bash 

#SBATCH -p my_partition
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --time 16:00:00          # format: HH:MM:SS
#SBATCH -N 1                     # 1 node
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=32     # tasks out of 128
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4             # gpus per node out of 4
#SBATCH --mem=246000             # memory per node out of 246000MB

#SBATCH hetjob

#SBATCH -p my_partition
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --time 16:00:00          # format: HH:MM:SS
#SBATCH -N 2                     # 2 nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=32     # tasks out of 128
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4             # gpus per node out of 4
#SBATCH --mem=246000             # memory per node out of 246000MB

#SBATCH hetjob

#SBATCH -p my_partition
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --time 16:00:00          # format: HH:MM:SS
#SBATCH -N 4                     # 4 nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=32     # tasks out of 128
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4             # gpus per node out of 4
#SBATCH --mem=246000             # memory per node out of 246000MB

#SBATCH hetjob

#SBATCH -p my_partition
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --time 16:00:00          # format: HH:MM:SS
#SBATCH -N 8                     # 8 nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=32     # tasks out of 128
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4             # gpus per node out of 4
#SBATCH --mem=246000             # memory per node out of 246000MB

#SBATCH hetjob

#SBATCH -p my_partition
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --time 16:00:00          # format: HH:MM:SS
#SBATCH -N 16                    # 16 nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=32     # tasks out of 128
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4             # gpus per node out of 4
#SBATCH --mem=246000             # memory per node out of 246000MB

srun --job-name=job1 --output=4cpu_%N_%j.out --het-group=0 script.sh 4

srun --job-name=job2 --output=8cpu_%N_%j.out --het-group=0 script.sh 8

srun --job-name=job3 --output=16cpu_%N_%j.out --het-group=0 script.sh 16

srun --job-name=job4 --output=32cpu_%N_%j.out --het-group=0 script.sh 32

srun --job-name=job5 --output=64cpu_%N_%j.out --het-group=1 script.sh 64

srun --job-name=job6 --output=128cpu_%N_%j.out --het-group=2 script.sh 128

srun --job-name=job7 --output=256cpu_%N_%j.out --het-group=3 script.sh 256

srun --job-name=job8 --output=512cpu_%N_%j.out --het-group=4 script.sh 512
```

Here `script.sh` takes as argument the number of processors and it is of the form

```
make cpp_program_I_need_to_run
mkdir -p my_results

mpirun -n $1 cpp_program_I_need_to_run

# other tasks
```

When I perform, on my cluster `sbatch slurm_script.slurm` jobs launched crash with exit code 8 and the following error(s):

```
cat slurm-8482798.out 
srun: error: r242n13: tasks 0-31: Exited with exit code 8
srun: launch/slurm: _step_signal: Terminating StepId=8482798.0
srun: error: r242n13: tasks 0-31: Exited with exit code 8
srun: launch/slurm: _step_signal: Terminating StepId=8482798.1
srun: error: r242n13: tasks 0-31: Exited with exit code 8
srun: launch/slurm: _step_signal: Terminating StepId=8482798.2
srun: error: r242n13: tasks 0-31: Exited with exit code 8
srun: launch/slurm: _step_signal: Terminating StepId=8482798.3
...
```

also

```
slurmstepd: error: Unable to create TMPDIR [/scratch_local/slurm_job.8482798]: Permission denied
slurmstepd: error: Setting TMPDIR to /tmp
slurmstepd: error: execve(): /cluster/home/userexternal/username/myfolder/script.sh: Exec format error
slurmstepd: error: execve(): /cluster/home/userexternal/username/myfolder/script.sh: Exec format error
...
```

and so on for many lines.

Is there a way to make it work? The only thing I can think is that the `mpirun` call in my `script.sh` is redundant, but then I don't have many ideas.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the mpirun command is redundant. Could you clarify what script.sh is expected to perform?

My approach would be to execute the make in advance, place `mkdir -p my_results` just after the `#SBATCH` directives (I assume the directory should be shared among all the job elements, otherwise you should use environment variables to point to node-local storage) and remove mpirun in favour of `srun ... cpp_program_I_need_to_run`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `script.sh` is expected to compile my code (actually is not mandatory for all the run, but some of them require particular compilation flags and I don't want to compile them manually or  have more than one executable at once), execute the compiled program, create a folder for the results if it has not been created yet and move files with results into the folder.
Actually only the execution of the program should be in parallel, all the other tasks can be performed sequentially, but I couldn't find a better way to automatize my tests

Comment: Do you mean that every het group should have its own binary compiled ad-hoc? Is there any communication between the jobs in the het-groups?